In Azure DevOps, link manual test cases with automated test scripts using PowerShell Pester Framework and CI/CD Pipeline
I have written automated tests using PowerShell Pester Framework. We have Azure DevOps for project management and I have the same TCs written in Test Plans -> Test Suites. We also are running the test in pipeline and it also publishes artifacts. The pipeline which is being run generates new record in Test Results with Run Id and the same test results are shown.
Now, the problem is the same results are not updating the test case results in Test Suite, in Progress Report Tab as well and I see for each manual test case, there is a sub-tab "Associated Automation" and those fields are in disabled state and I did many ways to bring the automation test scripts link up here but it didn't happen. I want to link the manual test cases with automation test scripts so whenever I run the pipeline it picks up and executes the result for each manual test case automatically.
I am using Intellij IDE and my Pester tests are as:
# Import Pester and Az Storage modules

Import-Module Pester
#Install-Module Az.Storage
Import-Module Az.Storage

# Define the Pester test script
Describe "Verify workflow trigger and validate the logs in Storage Table" {

    It "To trigger Azure Logic Apps workflow Interface" {
        $url = "<subject url>"

        # Headers for the request
        $headers = @{
            "Content-Type" = "application/json"
            "Accept" = "*/*"
        }

        # Body needs to be converted to JSON format
        $body = @{
            type = "charges"
            invoiceId = "invoice"
            reference = "761i6"
        } | ConvertTo-Json

        # Sending the POST request with JSON body
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $body

        # Validate the status code
        $response.StatusCode | Should -Be 200

        if ($response.StatusCode -eq "200") {
            Write-Host "Test passed: Response code is: 200"
        }
    }


    It "To verify Azure Logic Apps workflow in Storage Table" {
        $todayDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
        Write-Output $todayDate
        Write-Host "Today's date is: $todayDate"
        $todayDate | Should -Match "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"

        $appId = "<app id"
        $tenantId = "<tenant id>"
        $clientSecret = "<secret>"  # Mock value for client secret in tests
        $secureClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
        $psCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $appId, $secureClientSecret
        Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId
        $resourceGroupName = "<res group name>"
        $storageAccountName = "<storage acc name>"
        $tableName = "<storage table>"
        $storageKeys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
        $primaryKey = $storageKeys.Value[0]
#        Write-Host "Primary Key: $primaryKey"  # You can use Write-Host to print it in the console
#        Write-Output $primaryKey
        $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $primaryKey
        $storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $context
        $cloudTable = $storageTable.CloudTable
        $output = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -columnName "InterfaceId" -value "Invoice" -operator Equal

    }
}


Manual test cases are written with same names and are placed in Test Plan and Test Suite both with the same name given in "Describe" in above code.
My pipeline yaml has code to publish test results also consists the test plan id and test suite id:
# Publish the test results to the Azure DevOps Test tab with a custom name
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PesterReport/TestResults.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'Test Results'
    testSelector: 'testPlan'
    testPlan: '180'  # Reference the Test Plan ID
    testSuite: '221'  # Reference the Test Suite ID
    mergeTestResults: true


This is creating a record in Test Plans -> Runs -> Test Runs with the results but the same results are not being updated in Test Plans -> Test Suite -> Execute -> Outcome. And also not updated in Progress report tab. Here, I need to link the automation test scripts with manual test cases in Azure Devops work items. I see the Associated Automation fields are blank and in disabled mode. How to generate the automated test script under the fields.
WorkItemsAssociatedAutomationScreenShot
I am getting solutions where we can link from Visual Studio but not exactly from Intellij on Pester tests linking to test cases.

To link the test result with manual test cases, please have a check with similar ticket.

Thanks for information! But I am looking at linking manual test cases to automation test scripts in Azure Devops. For the work items in azure, I go to the test case id -> Associated Automation Tab-> I see the fields are blank and are in disabled mode.

As you already known, you can associate the test from Visual studio as mentioned in doc here. I'm afraid it's not supported to link test case script from Intellij on Pester tests.
